# Errors appears when creating table in oracle. What might be the mistake?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

```
CREATE TABLE users(
 id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 username varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
 email varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
 verified int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 token varchar2(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 password varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Can you share the error you're having?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax. Should be

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE users
  2  (
  3     id        INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  4     username  VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
  5     email     VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
  6     verified  INT DEFAULT 0  NOT NULL,
  7     token     VARCHAR2 (255),
  8     password  VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
  9     CONSTRAINT PK_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
 10  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

What you did wrong?

- there's no `auto increment`; from 12c you can use identity columns (as in my example; in lower versions, we did that with sequences and database triggers)
- first goes `default`, then `not null`
- `INT` datatype doesn't have *precision*
- no use in declaring a primary key column `not null`; primary key constraint won't let it anyway

---

As it turned out you're on 11g, then - as I said - identity column won't work. Here's a workaround:

```
SQL> create sequence sequ;

Sequence created.

SQL> create table users
  2  (
  3     id        int,
  4     username  varchar2 (100) not null,
  5     email     varchar2 (100) not null,
  6     verified  int default 0  not null,
  7     token     varchar2 (255),
  8     password  varchar2 (255) not null,
  9     constraint pk_id primary key (id)
 10  );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_pk_users
  2    before insert on users
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := sequ.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Also: an integer column should use a number as the default not a string, so `default 0` rather than `default '0'`

Comment: Ah, yes, @a_horse, thank you, fixed. Sandhya, *nothing* is missing - as you can see, table was created. Which database version do you use?

Comment: @Sandhya: you are probably using an outdated or unsupported Oracle version

Comment: I am using oracle of version 11g

Comment: Right, 11g. I edited my answer and added some more info. Have a look.

Comment: ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword

Comment: Table is created but the trigger shows error: Error at line 2: PLS-00201: identifier 'SEQU.NEXTVAL' must be declared

Comment: Did you create the sequence (as the first line in my example shows)?